# 301 Redirect from a url pattern with nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm trying to redirect `www.mysite.com/blog/` and `www.mysite.com/blog/*` URLs to a single page `www.mysite.com/news/`

I tried to achieve this with the following (inside a server block):

```
location /blog/ {
    return 301 $scheme://www.mysite.com/news/;
}
```

that didn't work as expected and then tried this:

```
rewrite ^/blog/.* /news/ permanent;
```

This too is not working i.e when I goto www.mysite.com/blog/ I get a page not found instead of getting redirected to /news/ page.

Is my approach correct? Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Describe 'not working'

Comment: The question cannot be answered without the full config.

Comment: If you have for example another location block with regular expression (e.g. location ~ \.php$), nginx will choose that one and never reach "location /blog/".

Comment: @JosefScript Yes, there are few other location blocks. I'll try to attach it to the question.